# How does a change in voltage affect a capacitor?

Tags: voltage, capacitor

If I increase the voltage between the capacitor's plates, what will be the effect on the capacitor? What would be the dependent and independent variables in this case?

Comment: What have you considered so far? How far do you think it is reasonable to explore independent variables - maybe you have an idea for a relevant (but possibly a little extreme) variable that maybe should be considered? Temperature? Humidity?

Comment: This question seems to be equivalent to "what is a capacitor?" which doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh, I think that's a precarious assumption. It could be that he has some training in science and is trying to understand something new analytically. One of the first questions a scientist might ask when learning something new might be "what are the dependent and independent variables?"

Comment: @trav1s Fair point. Also possible that searching the web before asking a question is too difficult for the OP.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh The web gives broad answers and may not even give the answers sometimes.If its too difficult for you to answer.I request you to kindly not breach here.

Comment: @Andyaka The extreme variables like temperature are not relevant here.

Comment: @SHAURYAMALWA Perhaps you might illuminate me on what "breaching here" entails... Or, you could first get a tutorial in English, followed by some basic tutorials in searching for information, and finally follow that up with a little training on how to treat with humility and respect people you are asking for help from... Or did you not notice who's asking for other people's volunteered time here?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh you could tell me about if i am unclear in my question.Instead of asking me to search the net.This site clearly mentions that "anyone can ask a question",and if your answer is to search for it.Well,you should concentrate on bettering your answering skills

Comment: @SHAURY See the site help: From [this page](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), "Have you **thoroughly searched** for an answer before asking your question? ... **Tell us what you found** and **why it didn’t meet your needs**. This demonstrates that you’ve **taken the time to try to help yourself**, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!". As someone who clearly is incapable of following site guidelines or tolerating feedback, you are hardly in a position to say what others "should concentrate on".

Comment: You really make me laugh @AnindoGhosh.Perhaps smoothing that ego would not hurt soo much.

Answer (score 5):

For an ideal capacitor, DC voltage bias is assumed to have no effect on capacitance.

However, for real capacitors, this is not true: A ceramic’s dielectric constant significantly changes under applied electrical field strength variations. Tantalum dielectric (oxide film Ta2O5) is not sensitive to such changes. Electrolytic capacitors in general are fairly stable to DC bias. See [this note](http://www.vishay.com/docs/40144/capchange.pdf) and [this one](http://www.niccomp.com/help/VoltageCoefficientofCapacitors-032012-R1.pdf) for further insight.

For ceramic capacitors, the following graph illustrates this variation:
[image: Capacitance graph against DC bias] <sub>([source](http://www.edn.com/design/analog/4402049/2/Temperature-and-voltage-variation-of-ceramic-capacitors--or-why-your-4-7--F-capacitor-becomes-a-0-33--F-capacitor))</sub>

- Actual capacitance reduces with increase of applied DC bias.
- Drop is more pronounced for smaller packages, and seems to stabilize for packages larger than 1210
- X7R or other dielectric types do not have any DC bias behavior specifications, so different X7R capacitors will behave differently.

**Summary:**

> **Read the datasheet.**

Comment: and lets not forget a varicap diode